# How to save url created by "Get a link" using "Move to" action

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, logic-app

I've a SPO site with a folder for attachments (images) and a document (Word, Excel or PP) in which I linked these attachments by option "Get a link": when I cut and paste attachments in a different folder these links keep on working but when I use the action "Move to" in a Logic App these links stop to work, clicking on it SPO can't find the resource.

How can I solve? Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my SharePoint Online environment but cannot reproduce your issue. The link still works after I use "Move to" button to move to another folder.

Whether all the files have this issue?

If the issue exists when you move to another library? Try to create a new library and check again.

Who would you like this link work for when you get the link?

Comment: Your answer let me hope but I need to give more details.

My SPO is set to **Classic Experience** and so I don't have any "Move to" button.

Besides of it **I don't need to move a file by SPO UI but by a Logic App that manages a workflow** and the Action "Move To" can't save the url got by "Get a link": when I paste the old url SPO says it can't find the resource.

I tried to use **Rest API "moveto"** (by PostMan, it is faster to explore): it works perfectly to move files within the same Document Library but… I continue in the next comment...

Comment: ... when I ask for moving files to another Document Library I get this message:
`
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2130246234, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "This operation is not supported."
        }
    }
}`
.

I hope you can help.